# Prevent datepicker from triggering parent mouseleave

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-events

I display an absolute `div` with a jQuery `$.animate({height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'})` on a jQuery `$.hover()`.

I have a jQuery UI datepicker attached to a div within the aforementioned absolute `div` with `changeMonth: true` and `changeYear: true`.

When a month or year are changed or a date is selected the animation fires.

How can I prevent the month/year change & date selection from triggering the `$.hover()`?

http://jsfiddle.net/e3zP2/

**html**

```
<div id="hoverAnchor">hover me</div>
<div id="hoverMe" style="display:none">
    arbitrary text
    <div id="dateSelector"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#dateSelector").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    
    $("#hoverAnchor").add($("#hoverMe")).hover(function(){
        $("#hoverMe").stop(true,false).animate({
            height: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }, 200);
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a couple things in order for this to work properly.

First, you need to wrap the HTML in a `div` to act as the container:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="hoverAnchor">hover me</div>
    <div id="hoverMe" style="display:none">arbitrary text
        <div id="dateSelector"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, rather than using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) (which can sometimes be unreliable), I recommend using [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) along with [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). Also use a `var` to hold boolean of whether datepicker open/closed. The reason for this boolean is due to the `input`.  On click, a second `.mouseenter()` event will be called, so without it, `#hoverme` would toggle a second time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dateSelector").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    var _enter = false;
    $("#container").add(
    $("#container")).mouseenter(function () {
        if (!_enter) {
            $("#hoverMe").stop(true, false).animate({
                height: 'toggle',
                opacity: 'toggle'
            }, 200);
        }
        _enter = true;
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        _enter = false;
        $("#hoverMe").stop(true, false).animate({
            height: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/e3zP2/18/

Hope this helps!

Comment: ty!  saw that it had to go to iteration 18.  gotta love those jquery ui limitations lol.  i modified without `#container`, and it worked.  am i missing something?  http://jsfiddle.net/e3zP2/23/  i have no idea how this working tho.  lol  thanks much!

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy no worries! the code will still work without using `#container`, however, the `#container` can act as a kind of buffer-zone.  Say you want to ensure the `#hoverme` doesn't toggle when you click an input value further down the list (try clicking `Dec` in month). You can then add `padding` to the container so it wraps around everything. Here is a demo to show what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/e3zP2/24/ . Only moving outside of that "buffer-zone" will cause `#hoverme` to toggle.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: do you think you could modify to help with this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197534/apply-parents-hover-to-jquery-ui-autocomplete-child