# apply parent's hover to jquery ui autocomplete child

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent, parent-child, jquery-autocomplete

I'm in a similar situation a my other problem [prevent datepicker from triggering parent mouseleave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195454/prevent-datepicker-from-triggering-parent-mouseleave/16196098?noredirect=1#16196098), but that solution doesn't seem to apply to jQuery UI autocomplete.

How can the hover also apply to autocomplete children?  In other words, if one `mouseenter`s on an autocomplete suggestion, `#hoverMe` should stay open.  Also, suggestion/code on how to handle `select`ing a selection that's outside of `#hoverMe` while keeping `#hoverMe` shown until one `mouseenter`s back in would be great!

http://jsfiddle.net/Kzp87/

**html**

```
<div id="hoverAnchor">hover me</div>
<div id="hoverMe" style="display:none">arbitrary text
    <input type="text" id="autocompletor"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $("#autocompletor").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    var _enter = false;
    $("#hoverAnchor").add($("#hoverMe")).mouseenter(function () {
        if (!_enter) {
            $("#hoverMe").stop(true, false).animate({
                height: 'toggle',
                opacity: 'toggle'
            }, 200);
        }
        _enter = true;
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        _enter = false;
        $("#hoverMe").stop(true, false).animate({
            height: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want the autocomplete to close when an item has been selected? Or, ideally, what would you like to happen? There are few ways to approach this.

Comment: @Dom I edited.  Basically, hovering a selection should keep `#hoverMe` shown.  I haven't really decided upon the behavior when `select`ing a selection that's outside of `#hoverMe`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];

    var _enter = false;
    $("#autocompletor").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            //in the event someone types into the input as #hoverMe is closing, this will prevent the list from showing
            if (!_enter) $('.ui-autocomplete').hide();
        }
    });

    $("#hoverAnchor").add($("#hoverMe")).mouseenter(function () {
        if (!_enter) {
            $("#hoverMe").stop(true, false).animate({
                height: 'toggle',
                opacity: 'toggle'
            }, 200);
        }
        _enter = true;
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        if (!$('.ui-autocomplete').is(':visible') && _enter) { //check if autocomplete is open
            $("#hoverMe").stop(true, false).animate({
                height: 'toggle',
                opacity: 'toggle'
            }, 200);
            _enter = false;
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Kzp87/3/

Basically, the list shows on `#hoverAnchor` and will remain showing until the mouse enters & leaves the `input` an additional time (however, we can always change this).  I used the [`open-event`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open) to prevent the list from showing if `#hideMe` is not visible.  Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: totally appreciate it dom!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the autocomplete not to vanish when you hover over the options you could use this:

```
$("ul.ui-autocomplete").appendTo($("div#hoverMe"))
```

This will append the list with the options to the div that is hoverable.
Unfortunately by default the parent element of the ul is the document so the hover is not applied.

This will cause the autocomplete to vanish once an option has been selected.